# Sorting on 2 columns in PHP without having to redo MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a $result variable in PHP from a MySQL query & I would like to sort it (with PHP) on 2 different columns.

I am doing this anytime a user clicks a different sort method, so I don't want to have to redo the MySQL query with ORDER BY ...., .... each time.

Comment: How many columns does your table have?

Comment: I gave you an answer for three columns. If you can't adjust it for your six columns, please edit your answer to mention your column names.

Comment: how do you not have to re-query the db when the user clicks a sort button? are you storing database results in a session or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be more efficient to have MySQL do the ordering for you, but if you want to do it in PHP, check out [usort](http://php.net/usort) which will let you sort an array using a callback function to decide the ordering.

If your $result is an array of associative database rows, here's a very simple example of using usort to sort on a string column 'foo' ...

```
//sort on string column
function sortStringFoo($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['foo'], $b['foo']);
}
usort($result, 'sortStringFoo');
```

Here's how you'd do a numeric sort...

```
//sort on numeric column
function sortNumericBar($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['bar'] == $b['bar']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['bar'] < $b['bar']) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($result, 'sortNumericBar');
```

That illustrates the basics of how to use usort, but how might we sort on several columns at once? Here's how we could combine our comparison callbacks to illustrate this by sorting on 'foo' and then 'bar'...

```
function sortFooBar($a,$b)
{
    $order=sortStringFoo($a,$b);
    if ($order==0)
       $order=sortNumericBar($a,$b);

    return $order;
}
usort($result, 'sortFooBar');
```

You could unroll `sortFooBar` into a single function, but this illustrates the technique: compare first column, if same, compare second column, and so on.

Comment: Saw usort earlier and tried it for about 30 mins. Couldn't figure out how to get it to solve my problem. Brain freeze!

Comment: THen you should post what you have!

Comment: @Paul Dixon: Did you even test this? It's totally useless, the last sorting will "ruin" the previous ones. Furthermore, no sorting is done with `strcmp`. Test it with the dummy data presented on my test case.

Comment: I would politely ask if you yourself tested it. The technique works just fine. You are correct strcmp doesn't sort, it's just used for comparison. The actual sorting is done by usort.

Comment: I see your misunderstanding - your example suggests you can use usort twice to sort by multiple columns, which is of course incorrect. See my final example for how multiple criteria can be used in a usort callback, I have clarified my answer to make this even clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by splitting all the columns of your table into separate arrays, then doing an [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) (notice example #3). Here is a test case:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Maria',
        'surname' => 'White',
        'age' => 24
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Brown',
        'age' => 32
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'surname' => 'Brown',
        'age' => 33
    )
);

$names      = array();
$surnames   = array();
$ages       = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $row){
    $names[$key]    = $row['name'];
    $surnames[$key] = $row['surnames'];
    $ages[$key]     = $row['age'];
}

// perform any sorting task you like
array_multisort($names, SORT_ASC, $surnames, SORT_ASC, $ages, SORT_DESC, $arr);

print_r($arr);
?>
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Brown
            [age] => 33
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Brown
            [age] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Maria
            [surname] => White
            [age] => 24
        )

)
```

If you split your columns into arrays, you have the power to sort by any column on any direction.

Comment: @Glyph: You are welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote count on the left hand side of my answer. :)

Comment: This technique is fine for small arrays, but for anything large it's very wasteful to duplicate the data into those secondary arrays just so you can use use array_multisort. When you use usort, the sorting occurs 'in place' without any such duplication.

Comment: @Paul Dixon: Provide a less resource hungry solution, and I would be happy to take a look at it. The solution you provide in your answer is not accurate, the least. Test it.

Comment: I'm starting to think redoing the query in MySQl would be better. I don't suppose MySQL has any options to resort? >.< Anyway, appreciate all the help! I would 'thumbs up' you but I just discovered this site, don't have any rep to spend yet.

Comment: Of course the best solution would be to run the query again with the new parameters. However, this solution will do just fine for you if you anticipate that your table won't have a huge number of rows, which will lead to out of memory errors.

Comment: @Shef - I didn't test it when I wrote it, my apologies. However, I fail to see where it is flawed, even when adapted for your test data.